# How to write a code to Move excel files based on FileName?

Tags: powershell

I would like to move excel files based on file's name on Server from one folder to another using Powershell.
For example:

```
\Desktop\SourceTestARC\ to \Desktop\DestinationTestARC\14_file,
\Desktop\SourceTestARC\ to \Desktop\DestinationTestARC\51_file, 
\Desktop\SourceTestARC\ to \Desktop\DestinationTestARC\55_file, etc.
```

Script should read first TWO digits of excel file and move it to the respective folder.

For example:

```
1420193344.dat goes to 14_file, 
51201997748.dat goes to 51_file.
```

Comment: Show in some [MCVE] what you have tried. StackOverflow is *not* a write-my-script service or a do-my-homework site. But to write a script, you need your brain and some basic [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) such as [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)

Comment: Hints: first step, find the basename (e.g. `14_file` for your first path). Second step: extract the first two characters of it. etc....

Answer (score 0):

Get-Childitems of the source-folder, then create a foreach loop.

Save the Filename in a variable, then use the $Variable.Substring Statement to get the necessary two digits, create a variable (e.g. $DestinationFolder) where you merge the source-folder with the the variable of the two digits.
Then use the Copy-Item Cmdlet to copy the file to the new destination, for the -destination Parameter use your $DestinationFolder variable.

Comment: Thank You for your response.. I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestARC\*.dat" | 
 ForEach { move -path $_ -destination ($_.directoryname +"\* -- "+ $_.Name.substring(0,2))}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
# Set the Path of the SourceFiles
$SourcePath = "C:\Users\Packard-User\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\"

# get all items of the folder
$FilesInFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath



foreach ($SourceFile in $FilesInFolder)
{

    # i dont like complex statements, because of that a use a helper variable
    $Helper1 = $SourceFile.Name

    # create the destination folder variable, take two characters from the beginning (0), adding the "\" is necessary to show it is a folder
    $DestinationFolder = $SourcePath+$Helper1.Substring(0,2)+"\"

    
    # create the destination folder, throws an exception if the folder already exists
    New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory

    # move the item to the destinationfolder
    Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile.FullName -Destination $DestinationFolder
    
    
}
```